# Non-mathematical description of manifolds and bundles in gauge theory

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, gauge-theory, soft-question, education

I am teaching myself gauge theory at the moment and occasionally I need to ask what may appear to be a very random or completely bizarre question that is way off, just in order to check if I have actually understood anything at all.

Here is one such question:  really ‘knowing’ very little about tangent bundles, is this topic linked to Covariant derivative and the connection which allows a smoothly continuous transformation such as parallel transport in GR?

I have only studied introductory GR, but I am correct in believing these topics come in once one starts studying intermediate or advanced GR.  Is that correct?

Is it really essential to have studied point topology and manifolds before one can gain some intuitive sense of what a gauge transformation is and how it can give rise to gauge bosons?

Comment: Note that this question may get closed as opinion-based and lacking a correct answer.

Comment: *Is it really essential to have studied point topology and manifolds  before one can gain some intuitive sense of what a gauge transformation is and how it can give rise to gauge bosons?* In my opinion, no. My graduate education covered QED and QCD without ever mentioning point topology, manifolds, tangent bundles, or connections in the QFT courses. But understanding how gauge theory and General Relativity are mathematically related was something I found very beautiful later when I learned about it after getting my degree.

Comment: *I have only studied introductory GR, but I am correct in believing these topics come in once one starts studying intermediate or advanced GR. Is that correct?*

Depends. Most GR books, even advanced ones, do not treat principal fibre bundles, and even if they do they usually just pay a lip service to them or use them for a very specifc purpose (like Wald).

The natural setting for gauge theories is principal fibre bundles and their associated (vector) bundles, so for the most part studying GR will not give you this knowledge.

Comment: Thanks.  That’s a really useful answer.

Comment: G Smith thank you for your answer.

Comment: I just found this on Arxiv.   Gauge Theories and Fiber Bundles: Definitions, Pictures, and Results
Adam Marsh
February 27, 2019.    https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.03089.pdf  It’s not too lengthy but look like it could help mr get a better understanding.